# Swift 4 / Objective-C instrospection

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a weird situation with unit tests that would be easily solved by a bit of an hack, and would like to know if this is easily doable as a temporary fix before tackling a major rewrite.

```
import Foundation

class Foo : NSObject {
    func bar() -> Void {
        // third-party code
    }
}
```

Is there any way that given `Foo.bar` would return the string `"-[Foo bar]"`

**Edit:** I didn't explain my situation well, sorry. I'm looking for something like a function:

```
MyStringifyingFunction(Foo.bar) // returns "-[Foo bar]"
```

This will be used to compare with `name` of a `XCTest` instance which is populated with the string `"-[MyTestClass testMethodOne]"` for example.

Comment: which `String` exactly? if you need the function's name you could use `"\(#function)"` in Swift and `@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__` in ObjC.

Comment: You want to translate swift into objective-C or what?

Comment: With regexes? https://regex101.com/r/ccCSX3/1

Comment: A Swift String to compare with the `name` parameter of `XCTest`, which when run is something like `"-[MyTestClass testMethod]"`. I would like to compare it from the object `MyTestClass.testMethod` instead of hardcoding the string.